# How can I base a query off of the current page post type AND a meta value from another custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have 2 custom post types: Communities and Testimonials.

I have a drop down menu in the Testimonials CPT that calls all of the communities. 
The drop down is using the ID of the community.

I have a a widget that shows all the testimonials. But if I'm on a Location A page, I want to show only testimonials from Location A.

I'm just not certain how to write that query. Thank you everyone in advance!

Comment: What makes a location "A" or not?

Comment: Each community has a category of the same name. So Location A page would be in category Location A.

Answer (score 0):

** Edited after large discussion below **

Ok so here is a link to a gist which should work.

If it does not, I'm honestly out of ideas, but this demonstrates how to set up a new query, including an example that should be pretty spot on to what you need, perhaps you may just need to change some values.

[Link to the Widget Gist](https://gist.github.com/aj-adl/bb023ce8fb98c1efa8d6)

There are some comments in there explaining some of the though processes, overall my reasoning was that if the meta-select field has a value of the post_ID for the location it belongs to, then when you are on that location's page the main $post->ID should be the value you need to search for when querying by the meta-key 'meta-select'.

If this doesn't work, try just inserting the query and loop into the template for the locations post type - if it works there but not in the widget that indicates that there is something wrong with your widget setup.

Overall, with the information I've given you here and a reasonable grasp of PHP you should be able to get this to work, if you don't know PHP at all and are just google-copy-pasting then troubleshooting this for your specific setup might be beyond your abilities and you should engage the (paid) services of a developer.

Comment: I did write the widget/function myself. Albeit with help from Google.

Comment: It looks like it's still pulling all of the posts, no testimonials at all. Here's my code as it sits right now:http://pastebin.com/M8VDLaR3

Comment: OK thanks, when you make references like `the_post()` you are referencing the main query, in order to get the desired result you need to specify the post object before calling the method - in our case this would look like `$testimonial_query->the_post();`

Also, in the query I wrote I have some placeholder terms -  'testimonial' and 'community' in the query need to be replaced with the name of the testimonials post type (set in your CPT), and community needs to be replaced with the meta key name of the custom field you are setting for each testimonial

Comment: Thank you for your help thus far. 
I've updated the pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/P25SeHR5

I changed the query, but now nothing is showing up. I feel like we're closer, but there's something I'm just not getting. I do have an array I'm printing out to see if maybe I could identify what I'm missing. I couldn't. :(

Comment: Try this, I've cleaned up a few things that may have been causing conflict. [link to gist](https://gist.github.com/aj-adl/bb023ce8fb98c1efa8d6)

Comment: Again, thank you very much. Unfortunately It's still producing nothing. I'm wondering if I'm explaining something wrong? Each testimonial is assigned a location ID. If you're on one of those location pages, I want to show only those testimonials.

I should mention this is in a widget. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: How is it assigned a location ID? Is this a taxonomy? A post meta field? If so what is the meta key for this field? Also how is this ID worked out? Actual ID of the location page? An ID Number you made up? ambiguous terms make solving the issue quite hard

Comment: Terribly sorry for the ambiguity, believe me it's not on purpose. I made a function that grabs all the locations and puts them in a drop down. The value of the drop down selection is the ID of that location. When you're on a testimonial add/edit page you select a location.  Does that make sense?  To answer your question, the testimonial uses a meta box to grab all the locations.

Comment: Ok, and where is the list of locations and their corresponding ids defined? Is it using the post Id if the location? And I really so need the meta key of that location is field - what are you saving this custom field as in the database?

Comment: Locations is a custom post type. 
Testimonials is a custom post type. 
I am using the post ID for the location. (this is inside of the testimonials CPT meta box). 
The meta key is literally "meta-select". I know that is a horrible naming convention. Just wanted to get it working.